# Writing multiline variable to file cmd

Tags: windows, jenkins, groovy, cmd, jenkins-pipeline

I am writing multiple lines in a variable to a file as part of my build step in groovy jenkins.

```
def output = GetProfiles()
String[] rev = output.toString().split("\n");
for(int i=0;i<rev.length;i++) {
    String cred = rev[i]
    bat "@echo off && echo $cred >> \"$tmpDir\\credentials\""
}
```

**GetProfiles** returns multiple lines of data and the above code works. However, it takes alot of time as it writes to the file line by line.

Is there a better approach to writing the entire set of lines in the variable to a file in one go? I tried encasing the **echo** command in `()` but that doesn't work.

```
  bat "@echo off && (echo $output) > \"$tmpDir\\credentials\""
```

Comment: Check out the [writeFile](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace) Jenkins keyword, which allows you to easily write strings into a file using the desired encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def output = GetProfiles().toString()
writeFile( file: "$tmpDir/credentials", text: output )
```